# Trouble importing geopandas

Tags: python, jupyter, geopandas

I've spent the last 5 hours googling to try to fix this error, but nothing has worked so far. When I do `import geopandas as gpd` I get the following error

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/paransonthalia/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fiona/ogrext.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libkea.1.4.7.dylib
```

Referenced from: /Users/paransonthalia/anaconda3/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found

I have tried reinstalling anaconda, creating new venv's, and more, but nothing yet.

Anything helps!

Comment: Are you using the same version of python, i.e. this **occurs** if you have installed anaconda with python 3.7, but in the environment you create you use python 3.6, I haven't been able to figure out why it happens, but yes, try this and let me know if it works for you. So to avoid this, use the same version of Python that you have installed as the version of python for your Virtual env.

Comment: Also check out this thread, it is for MacOS but this is from where I fixed my issue when I faced it. (I use windows)

Comment: Thanks for your response! The python with which I installed and the python version in my notebook is 3.7.3. Also, which thread are you taking about?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the link https://github.com/conda-forge/geopandas-feedstock/issues/45 , also if the venv version is same as master install both 3.7 you might be interested to check from here in that link https://github.com/conda-forge/geopandas-feedstock/issues/45#issuecomment-471705768

Comment: Still isn't working :(

Comment: I will try to reproduce the error later and solve it, no promises though :)

Comment: My new error is this when I try to install geopandas
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(568): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::python.app-2-py37_9'.
I've tried the sudo chown command, but still doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you give in more detail the different steps you took to create the new environment and then to import geopandas? That might help us spot how to solve it.

Comment: I used these steps to create the environment: https://github.com/conda-forge/geopandas-feedstock/issues/45#issuecomment-473987858   At this point, any conga command gives me the same error as above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: if it gave you the exact same error, then your path isn't properly set and/or you're launching the wrong installation of python

Comment: I think it might be with python since I have been messing with that a lot. I'm worried that I am not checking if the python version is correct correctly. How shoudl I go about doing that? Thanks!